# Did Ackermann produce a finitary consistency proof of second-order $PRA$?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, math-history, philosophy

In Wilhelm Ackermann's Doctoral Thesis (it is claimed, by Richard Zach, for one, in his paper "The Practice of Finitism: Epsilon Calculus and Consistency Proofs in Hilbert's Program", arXiv: math/0102189v1 [mathLO] 24 Dec. 2001) there is a finitary proof of second-order $PRA$ (Primitive Recursive Arithmetic--Note also Zach states that Hilbert gave a finitary proof of $PRA$ in his lectures of 1921-22 and 1922-23).  Is this true, and did Hilbert and Bernays recognize it as finitary?  Also, is there an English translation of his thesis?  Third, could someone give a short, precise synopsis of Hilbert's proof of the consistency of $PRA$?  That would be very much appreciated.

Comment: @Normal:  There.   Better?

Comment: What does PRA stand for ?

Comment: @Peter:  Primitive Recursive Arithmetic.  This is in the corrected question.

Comment: For Hilbert's lectures, see [here](https://books.google.it/books?id=v7YfBAAAQBAJ&pg=PR3).

Comment: For Ackermann dissertation, see **1.6.3 Ackermann and von Neumann on Epsilon Substitution**, in Paolo Mancosu, [The adventure of Reason: Interplay Between Philosophy of Mathematics and Mathematical Logic, 1900-1940](https://books.google.it/books?id=LZzFAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA75) (2010), page 75-on.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA:  Thanks for the references.  Very helpful (especially the Mancosu, since it is in English).  I guess I can presume Hilbert deemed the consistency proof in Ackermann's thesis "finitary"(?)  If so, why don't we?

Comment: A further source of info can be : Kurt Gödel, [Collected Works. Volume I](https://books.google.it/books?id=WhB7jgEACAAJ) (1986), page 196-on, where S.Feferman discuss the background of Gödel's review of an Hilbert's foundational paper *Die Grundlegung der elementaren Zahlenlehre* (1931).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA:  Again, excellent references, and very helpful.  The information in Mancosu's book would serve as an answer I would accept, if you wish to give such as an answer.